# ROWLOCK in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table to update with no indexing in the where clause so I use ROWLOCK in the update script, hoping to get row lock instead of table lock but no luck.. so what is the function of the ROWLOCK then? I was using it in the select statement but still locking the entire table... so annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you selecting too many rows - Sql Server will escalate lock to table level. Instead you may hit the cap of possible locks count or memory

**OR**

You use `SNAPSHOT` isolation level - then you may only apply `ROWLOCK` hint with `HOLDLOCK` or `UPDLOCK` hints simultaneously

**Update:**

You may frame your statement with

```
DBCC TRACEON(-1,3604,1200) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;

Here is your statement

DBCC TRACEOFF(-1,3604,1200) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

and see - which locks are taken, held and released during the run

**UPDATED**:

DBCC TRACEON (-1, 3604, 1200)

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE [Order]

with (ROWLOCK)

SET ProductId = 3

WHERE CustomerId = 1

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Process 54 acquiring IX lock on OBJECT: 16:229575856:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 54 acquiring IU lock on PAGE: 16:1:196 (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 54 acquiring U lock on RID: 16:1:196:0 (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 54 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 16:1:196 (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 54 acquiring X lock on RID: 16:1:196:0 (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 54 releasing lock reference on RID: 16:1:196:0

Process 54 acquiring U lock on RID: 16:1:196:1 (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 54 releasing lock on RID: 16:1:196:1

Process 54 releasing lock reference on PAGE: 16:1:196

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: in fact only 2 records in the table and the filter will select only one record. but why getting table lock instead??

Comment: WHICH table lock you get? - You obviously will get the Sch-S on Table level and IU IX l locks on table and page levels. It is an intended behavior

Comment: @user384080: I wonder if it's because locking one row of a 2-row table is effectively locking *half* of the table. Did you try your ROWLOCK update on a 10-row table? 50-row table?

Comment: @Andriy.. the production database has million of records and the ROWLOCK is actually acquiring the table lock so i just created a new database for testing and indeed ROWLOCK has no purpose!

Comment: Its all OK - only ROWLOCK was taken over updated rows, and as I said before - Intent locks over PAGE and TABLE also held - its by design

Comment: @Oleg..  why (by default) the PAGE and TABLE lock were also held? what is the purpose of ROWLOCK then if at the end SQL Server will always try to obtain the PAGE/TABLE lock?

Comment: These Page and Table locks are **INTENT** locks - how does them working see here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry mate.. i'm too slow.. still dont get it.. why does SQL Server want to acquire a shared (S) lock or exclusive (X) lock on some of the resources lower down in the hierarchy?

Comment: Say... Because if it locking row for update - it has to know that for example - you cannot modify the table structure. And for knowing that it places lock (Sch-lock) on table. It is not "real" lock, but intention - see lock compatibility matrix

Comment: one last question.. if i apply clustered index on customerId then sql server will do index seek which will require KEY lock instead off RID lock.. in this case, why sql server does not lock the entire table while it's still acquiring IX lock on PAGE?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6868/discussion-between-user384080-and-oleg-dok)